# Inherit CSS from parent component in Angular Application

Tags: html, css, angularjs, inheritance

I am building an application that I have to hard 'reset' all default CSS that is applied by browsers.

However, I'm having to copy/paste this in for each `xxx.component.css` because it doesn't appear to inherit any of the css from the baseline `app.component.css`.

Everything sits under the `app.component.html` template like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-left-nav></app-left-nav>
  <app-top-nav></app-top-nav>
  <app-todo-section></app-todo-section>
  <app-details-section></app-details-section>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to configure CSS inheritance in Angular? Should it be happening by default?

Here's a snippet of the 'Reset' code in the `app.component.css`:

```
html,
body,
div,
span,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? If code example is needed, let me know!

Comment: can you place a code sample with the css?

Comment: @Aruna From which file specifically? I've pasted a snippet of the `app.component.css` reset. I'm having to paste this code in each Angular `component.css` file

Comment: can you put your angular code and in which view it worked and not worked?

Comment: @Aruna Why? There's no 'Worked' and 'Not worked' in this case. The css from my `app.component.css` isn't being applied to child components, so I'm manually applying it to the `xxx.component.css` which goes against DRY principles. There's a lot of files involved here, what do you specifically want to see?

Answer (score 1):

In angular each component has its own css. According to the [angular 6 documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#styles-in-component-metadata) this styling only applies for components. Angular achieves this by setting an attribute for every html element and on every css selector in a component. E.g.:

**html**

```
<nav _ngcontent-c2="" id="main-navigation">
  <ul _ngcontent-c2="">
    <li _ngcontent-c2="" routerlink="/dashboard" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/dashboard"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c2="" routerlink="/inbox" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/inbox"></li> 
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**css**

```
#main-navigation[_ngcontent-c2] > ul[_ngcontent-c2] > li[_ngcontent-c2] {
    flex: 1;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(240, 240, 256);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**If you want to use styling that applies to all elements add it to the `src/styles.css` file. But even then it can be a bit tricky since angular adds in a html-tag for each component you add.**

Answer (score -3):

No matter what framework you use, your CSS will *always* be inherited according to the CSSOM. So if your CSS is not working on child components, do the following:

1. See if the CSS file with the default styles are being loaded on the corresponding page
2. See if there are any overriding CSS styles that you or any framework you might be using, in the corresponding pages.

**TL;DR:** Yes, it *should* happen by default

Having said that, you should note that **some CSS properties are not inherited**. See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) for a full list of CSS inheritance rules

Of the properties you've used, the following aren't inherited:

- margin
- padding
- border
- vertical-align

However, if it's just the HTML tags that you've defined in the list that you need to have your CSS applied to, this shouldn't matter. The above only applies if you want **inheritance**